# to display message in same form page

Tags: php, forms, message

I need to add a notification to this page saying " Thank you for your feedback"
However,the notification did not appear at the correct place,which is above the form.

This is my code.

```
      $message="tq 4 feedback";
      $common->display_message($message);
```

This is where the feedback form.
The function i'm using is

```
    function display_message($message) {
print $message;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why if you have the message already you are passing it to a function to display, but you need to "return" the variable from the function.  Then you can echo it out wherever you need to.

```
function display_message($message) {
    return $message;
}
```

To call it:

```
$message="tq 4 feedback";
$returned_message = $common->display_message($message);
```

And place it where you want:

```
echo $returned_message;
```

or just:

```
$message="tq 4 feedback";
echo $common->display_message($message);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably an issue with your view, to be honest. What's your view look like?

Comment: it is a feedback form.when the user click on submit button,i want the message saying "thanx for your feedback" to appear at the same page.